# Shifting dataframe index to match another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data-frames.  I am trying to update one data-frame with another.

`df1` looks like:

```
            col2  col3 dept
date                       
2020-05-08    29    21    A
2020-05-09    56    12    B
2020-05-10    82    15    C
2020-05-11    13     9    D
2020-05-12    35    13    E
2020-05-13    53    87    F
2020-05-14    25     9    G
2020-05-15    23    63    H
```

and `df2` looks like:

```
            col2 dept
date                 
2020-05-08    64    A
2020-05-09    41    B
2020-05-10    95    C
2020-05-11    58    D
2020-05-12    89    E
2020-05-13    37    F
2020-05-14    24    G
2020-05-15    67    H
```

I can update `df1` with `df2` no problem when the dates in the index of both data-frames match using:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('dept', append=True)
df2 = df2.set_index('dept', append=True)
df1.update(df2)
df1 = df1.reset_index(level='dept')
df2 = df2.reset_index(level='dept')
```

The above brings dept into the index and I update `df1` with `df2`

So `col2` in `df1` is updated with the output being:

```
           dept  col2  col3
date                       
2020-05-07    A    64    21
2020-05-08    B    41    12
2020-05-09    C    95    15
2020-05-10    D    58     9
2020-05-11    E    89    13
2020-05-12    F    37    87
2020-05-13    G    24     9
2020-05-14    H    67    63
```

However - when the index dates are different for example when df2 looks like:

```
            col2 dept
date                 
2020-05-07    64    A
2020-05-08    41    B
2020-05-09    95    C
2020-05-10    58    D
2020-05-11    89    E
2020-05-12    37    F
2020-05-13    24    G
2020-05-14    67    H
```

Using the above code `df1` does not update with the values from `df2`.  How can I update a date-frame with another data-frame when the index is different? A solution is to make the dates in `df2` the same as `df1` then that will be fine (but how would you do that).

Comment: Not sure if understand, do you need rewrite index from `df2` by`df2.index` like `df1.index = df2.index` before your solution?

Answer (score 3):

You want to update `df1` from `df2` on a combination of indexes(`date` and `dept`).

**Your same code would have worked fine, only if you would have had matching indexes across dataframes.**

The indexes for df1 after `df1 = df1.set_index('dept', append=True)` are:

```
In [160]: df1.index.tolist()                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[160]: 
[('2020-05-08', 'A'),
 ('2020-05-09', 'B'),
 ('2020-05-10', 'C'),
 ('2020-05-11', 'D'),
 ('2020-05-12', 'E'),
 ('2020-05-13', 'F'),
 ('2020-05-14', 'G'),
 ('2020-05-15', 'H')]
```

Taking your second `df2` for example. Index for `df2` after `df2 = df2.set_index('dept', append=True)` are:

```
In [159]: df2.index.tolist()                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[159]: 
[('2020-05-07', 'A'),
 ('2020-05-08', 'B'),
 ('2020-05-09', 'C'),
 ('2020-05-10', 'D'),
 ('2020-05-11', 'E'),
 ('2020-05-12', 'F'),
 ('2020-05-13', 'G'),
 ('2020-05-14', 'H')]
```

You can see that **indexes of both dataframes do not match** for any row. Hence, it did not update. If you would have had matching indexes, you would get desired output from your code itself.